# Query SQL DB for a specific string within a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a rails app and I am looking to create an action in my controller that query's my SQLite DB and returns a Link that has a specific string in a DB column.

For instance I have a `links` table with a column `category`. I want my controller to get all categories that have a string of `movies`.

What does this Query look like? I posted my schema and controller that I have so far, but I am stuck.

links_controller:

```
  def find_category
    Link.where("SELECT category FROM links WHERE links LIKE '%movies%'")
  end
```

links table:

```
  create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total", default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score", default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",    default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",  default: 0
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "category"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for a `LIKE` query. You may want to use `distinct` to select duplicate values just once.

```
Link.distinct(:category).where("category LIKE ?", "%movies%").pluck(:category)
```

If you want to package it in a method

```
def find_category
  Link.distinct(:category).where("category LIKE ?", "%movies%").pluck(:category)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Simone, this is getting the string now. Would you happen to know how I could get the contents of the object that contains that string? Put another way, how I could get the rest of the specific Link instance containing 'movies' is associated with?

Comment: I could create another question if it would help

Comment: You can't, if you use distinct. In order to get all the Links, when you have to take out `distinct` and `pluck`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_category
    Link.where("SELECT category FROM links WHERE links LIKE '%movies%'")
  end
```

You reference 'links' twice in that query, should it not be `WHERE category LIKE %movies%`